# european version of unbounce.com / landing page generator

Tags: hosting, html

All the landing page generators i found are horribly outdated, except for unbounce.com which seems to be pretty fine. However, from my location (germany), ping times are 0.5-1s which is way too slow for any snappy first impression. So do you know a way to host their landing pages in europe of an european competitor?

Cheers, Hajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there - I'm one of the co-founders of Unbounce and just wanted to let you know that we're planning on adding more data center locations around the globe in early 2011. We use AWS and just have a bit of infrastructure work to do on our end before we can expand. That being said, some customers of had luck using http://www.cloudflare.com/ - a caching proxy service.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about setting up my own proxy on our local servers but that looks even simpler :)

Comment: No problem, just had one more customer hook them up after seeing this comment and report a successful bump in speed. Good luck! Hopefully we'll have more servers running worldwide before too long...